# Importing modules/functions: does every line get executed?

Tags: python

I'm curious if what I'm seeing is a bug, a feature of python, or maybe I've placed code in the wrong blocks.

I have written some functions and then placed some lines of code testing them, in a file called "thermal model function":

```
thermal_model_functions.py:

def determine_final_temperature(wind_speeds, convection_values):

   ## Do some stuff here

   return temperature_value

#Here, I run some extra commands
print("Extra commands")
```

What I noticed is that when I import the above script into a second python script, the "Extra Commands" get run too; the output from print("Extra commands") gets shown on my console.

Am I maybe leaving the indent in the wrong place? Please note that when I import the script, I use

```
from thermal_model_functions import define_final_temperature
```

Comment: when you import a file in python it exec the file automatically... but if you want to put some code that works only when the module is executed directly you can use "if \__\__name\__\__ == '\__\__main\__\__': do_stuff_on_directly_execution()" in default indentation on the module file.

Comment: Any top-level statements in a module are executed when the module is first loaded.